# Windows 7 problems when relying on "sleep mode" rather than shutting down

Tags: windows-7, windows, sleep, shutdown, mode

After not restarting/shutting down the computer for about a week (I just leave it in sleep mode when not using it), a huge performance drop occurs. Any application loads very slowly, and apparently there are some rendering issues too like the one shown in the image (it happens after switching windows or minimizing/maximizing).

Is there a particular reason for this to happen? And besides restarting/shutting down is there a way to avoid this problem?

[image]

Comment: How much RAM do you have? What does Task Manager tell you about the resource use during the slowness?

Comment: Does it stay slow or speed up a bit later after coming out of sleep?

Answer (score 0):

This particular issue relatively depends on drivers, that could cause this issue. Please update device drivers including chipset driver, mouse driver and display card driver. You can check and list the devices which may cause this issue using the below command:

```
powercfg -devicequery wake_from_any
```

Please try update the device drivers and check the outcome.

Hope this helps.